# How can we return a static reference to a variable we make in a function in rust?

Tags: rust, reference

```
struct Foo<'a>(&'a str);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'static str {self.0}
}
fn main() {
    let value: &str;
    {
        let foo = Foo("Test Value");
        value = foo.get();
    }
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

In this test code, I need to get the value stored in foo but as str is not sized, I can't just copy it's value. I even tried cloning the str. In a real life scenario, I could just use String or make a wrapper or encapsulate it in a box and return it but is there no way I can return a static reference to a variable I create in a function? If so, how does the **as_str** function work in rust?

----Edit----

In this example, Neither putting 'static before str in Foo nor returning value with lifetime 'a works. What to do then?

```
struct Foo<'a>(&'a [i32]);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'static [i32] {self.0}
}
fn main() {
    let value: &[i32];
    {
        let test_value = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        let foo = Foo(&test_value);
        value = foo.get();
    }
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

Comment: Does this : https://users.rust-lang.org/t/return-static-ref-from-function/51042 answer your question ? Essentially : you should not return static references

Comment: Ok, I will try to use as few static references as possible but I would still like for my functions to return a static reference when the value is independent to the reference example while returning a slice. I may be able to work around it by using a wrapper like a vector or an array but it often may happen that I want the lifetime of a value I initialize to be more than the value inputted in the function by returning a static reference trimmed down to the lifetime of the variable I want it for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
struct Foo<'a>(&'a str);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a str {self.0}
}
fn main() {
    let value: &str;
    {
        let foo = Foo("Test Value");
        value = foo.get();
    }
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

Or like this:

```
struct Foo(&'static str);
impl Foo {
    fn get(&self) -> &'static str {self.0}
}
fn main() {
    let value: &str;
    {
        let foo = Foo("Test Value");
        value = foo.get();
    }
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

The reason your code doesn't compile is that you're declaring you are returning a reference with a (potentially) longer lifetime. Compare the lifetime of `static` with that of `a` (`self.0` has a lifetime of `a`).

Comment: Thanks but is there any way I could make a value in heap that does not get deleted after the function ends and return a reference to that such that it does drop the value after the variable it is assigned to leaves the scope?

Comment: You can take a look at the various [Smart Pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html) Rust provides, the simplest of which is [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html).

Comment: Can you please tell me how I could go about implementing using Box in the code in the edit of the question?

Comment: @RamanAgrawal They return based on the lifetime of `self`.

Comment: I know that because if it is related to a reference to a data in the struct, then it can only exist till the object does, but is there a way to clone the data to an empty location and pass its reference with its reference being static or it existing till the object using it exists?